# Count list length in a column of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my Dataframe:

```
CustomerID  InvoiceNo
0   12346.0 [541431, C541433]
1   12347.0 [537626, 542237, 549222, 556201, 562032, 57351]
2   12348.0 [539318, 541998, 548955, 568172]
3   12349.0 [577609]
4   12350.0 [543037]
```

Desired Output:

```
 CustomerID InvoiceCount
0 12346.0   2
1 12347.0   6
2 12348.0   4
3 12349.0   1
4 12350.0   1
```

I want to calculate the total number of Invoice a customer(CustomerID) have.
Please help.

Comment: do you have `InvoiceNo` as `list` or `string` with list ?

Comment: InvoiceNo is a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this works:

```py
df["InvoiceCount"] = df['InvoiceNo'].str.len()
```

Comment: This will only work if the column is not a string, try `df['col'].str.replace('\[|\]','').str.split(',').str.len()` if it doesnt work in the first instance

Answer (score 0):

If you have real `list` then you can do

```
df['InvoiceCount'] = df['InvoiceNo'].apply(len)
```

If you have `string` with list then you would have to convert string to real list before count

```
df['InvoiceNo'] = df['InvoiceNo'].apply(eval)
```

But it may not work if number `C541433` (with `C`) is correct and may need

```
df['InvoiceCount'] = df['InvoiceNo'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(',')))
```

or similar to example in @Datanovice comment

```
df['InvoiceCount'] = df['InvoiceNo'].str.split(',').str.len()
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = '''CustomerID;InvoiceNo
12346.0;[541431, 541433]
12347.0;[537626, 542237, 549222, 556201, 562032, 57351]
12348.0;[539318, 541998, 548955, 568172]
12349.0;[577609]
12350.0;[543037]'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=';')

print( df['InvoiceNo'].apply(lambda x: len(eval(x))) )

print( df['InvoiceNo'].apply(eval).apply(len) )

print( df['InvoiceNo'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(','))) )

print( df['InvoiceNo'].str.split(',').str.len() )

df['InvoiceNo'] = df['InvoiceNo'].apply(eval)
print( df['InvoiceNo'].apply(len) )
```

Comment: It's a list. df['InvoiceCount'] = df['InvoiceNo'].apply(len)  ---> This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If thats in a list, you can use the function 'len'

So let's say the list is in the variable values:

```
values = [537626, 542237, 549222, 556201, 562032, 57351]
```

then the amount is:

```
len(values) # 6
```

this would return 6 in this example